# Android studio - Proyecto lento en app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: android-studio

Llevo trabajando en un proyecto bastante tiempo y de repente se ha vuelto excesivamente lento a la hora de compilar, en `app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac` ha tardado 30 min.

Alguna idea de que puede ser?

aquí os paso mi build.gradle

un saludo

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "2.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'

    api 'com.google.code.gson:gson:+'
    api 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'


    api 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.0'

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'


    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:' + rootProject.navigationVersion
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:' + rootProject.navigationVersion

    implementation 'com.github.fafaldo:fab-toolbar:1.2.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1'
    }



    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'

    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Solución**
Al final de muchas pruebas he encontrado la solución por mi mismo.
Hay que entrar en File ->Setting ->Version Control -> Background y quitar la selección de los tres primeros checks.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer Build -> Clean Project luego Build -> Rebuild Project

Estas opciones la encuentras en la barra superior del ide

Comment: por favor argumenta tu respuesta

Comment: Lo intenté eso y no mejora. También he resintalado Android studio y nada.

Comment: No todo se resuelve con Build > Clean project! :-(